# Apply custom styles to ngbtooltip in angular

Tags: css, styles, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want to apply custom style to my `tooltip` as shown in image.

[image]

Please help me..
Thanks

Comment: @Paulie_D I already searched out for this and tried many ways, but I didn't get the output that's why I asked the question. If you really know the answer then please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the style with the attribute [tooltipClass](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api) and a style for the new class.

```html
<button type="button" ngbTooltip="Upload new document" tooltipClass="my-custom-class">
  <img src="plus_button.jpg">
</button>
```

```css
.my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
   background-color: lightblue;
}

.my-custom-class .arrow::before {
   border-top-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer. This is the answer to get desire output

```
<a class="btn mr-5" ngbTooltip="Upload new documents" tooltipClass="custom-tooltip" placement="bottom">
   <img src="/assets/images/instantiate-worklist-btn.png" />
</a>

.custom-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background: #59ADFF !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 300px;
}

.custom-tooltip .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: #59ADFF !important;
}
```